# Different hosts (Pods in Kubernetes) responds with different certificate for the same hostname

Tags: nginx, ssl, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, tls1.2

I have a werid problem - when asking for my internal hostname, `xxx.home.arpa` via e.g  `openssl s_client -connect xxx.home.arpa:443` one (example) pod

```yaml
 -  image: docker.io/library/node:8.17.0-slim
    name: node
    args:
      - "86400"
    command:
      - sleep
```

is getting response with **DEFAULT NGINX INGRESS CERTIFICATE**.

Other pod in the same namespace **for the same command** is getting response with my **custom certificate**.

**Question:**
Why one pod RECEIVES different cert for the same request?

For the purpose of this problem, please assume that cert-manager and certs should be properly configured - they are working in most of the system, it's only few pods that are misbehaving

**Configuration**: k8s nginx ingress, calico CNI, custom coredns svc which manages DNS responses (might be important?), my own CA authority.

e:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: ca-issuer
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  creationTimestamp: "2022-03-13T06:54:17Z"
  generation: 1
  name: gerrit-ingress
  namespace: gerrit
  resourceVersion: "739842"
  uid: f22034ab-0ed8-4779-b01e-2738e6f63eb7
spec:
  rules:
  - host: gerrit.home.arpa
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: gerrit-gerrit-service
            port:
              number: 80
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - gerrit.home.arpa
    secretName: gerrit-tls
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 192.168.10.2
```

Most of the configuration (Except DNS) [is up here](https://github.com/Venthe/Personal-Development-Pipeline/blob/develop/provisioning/cluster_vagrant/provisioning/1.10_ingress.yml).

Comment: Can you post the ingress spec to the question.

Comment: @gohm'c yes, edited into question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, my initial guesses were far off - particular container had a set of tools which were both configured to not send servername (Or not support SNI at all, which was the problem), specifically `yarn:1.x` and `openssl:1.0.x`.

The problem was with SNI of course, newer openssl or curl do use -servername by default satisfying SNI requirements.

To this I've considered two solutions:

- Wildcard DNS for the clients that do not support SNI, which is easier but does not feel secure
- TLS termination with reverse proxy allowing me to transparently use client with SNI support, which I haven't yet tried.

I went with wildcard DNS, though I don't feel that this should be done in prod. :)